# What does ' sign mean in RegularExpression attribute?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I have this regular expression:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$")]
```

I would like to know what `'` sign means?  and what is its meaning in this regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'
```

means it use as a separation between two words as you are having in above code.

or you can say separation of a code.

and '\ use for set the text as a string.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$")]
```

above code meaning:

```
[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40} match a single character present in the list below

Quantifier: {1,40} Between 1 and 40 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
' the literal character '
'-' a single character in the range between ' and '
\s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
```

Comment: Your comment on the 'Quantifier' doesn't make much sense. It's min-max length of the matched range.